Is there any use for a top-level global variable declaration?
In Python, the global declaration is used inside function definitions to specify that assigning the variable will create/update a global variable, rather than the default local variable.
Python also allows the global statement outside of function definitions. This doesn't cause an error, which leads many beginners to misuse it by writing the top-level declaration once instead of putting it in each function that needs it.
It seems like this should be a syntax error, like using return outside a function or break outside a loop. Do these declarations serve any purpose, which would explain why it's allowed?

If it works, and doesn't cause an error, it seems to me that it could say that you really meant for this to be a global.

After my  answer I re-read this and got the point  - the problem might be that newcomers coming specifically from "C"ish languages will think they don't need to declare it as global inside the functions. I guess the thing to do is to unleash the linters at them :-)

@jsbueno do you know how long a newcomer can go without ever running a linter?

Maybe some 10, 20 years. Python is not C - there is a different syntax, and different rules. They will have to be told about not abusing global variables at some point as well -- and either way, the code written mistakenly in this way will simply never work, not even once - that is supposed to get them on track.

@jsbueno global variables have never been a good idea no matter the language.  The worst code I ever had to work on was in C from someone who was hesitant to use parameter passing and used globals everywhere instead.

@jsbueno I'm not sure how many of them are coming from another language. I'm pretty sure that the vast majority of python questions we get here are from people totally new to programming and it's their first and only language. And we see this error frequently.

A person not having learned "global" in C has no motive whatsoever, ever, to think that a top-;evel global statement would behave the way you describe (the C way).
They will first have to understand how variable works - then how function scoping works, and when that is underway, all that is needed is a single phrase like "See: any variables inside functions are contained to the function - but there is a way to affect variables outside it, by using the 'global' keyword inside the function"

@jsbueno What probably happens is that they read somewhere that you use the global statement to create a global variable, but miss or don't understand the detail that it has to be used in the specific functions that assign it. Beginners have lots of confusion about how to use global variables in python (they often don't realize you don't need it when you only read the variable or assign to its attributes/indexes).

they just are not an error, and do no harm, Remember that Python was created as a permissive first language, and remained so for over 2 decades.  In recent years,  this feelings had shifted among some language user demographics, which prefer explicitly settling for a more restrictive use of the language.
It makes no sense to directly disallow a harmless permitted usage of global or other kwyeword though. For those who prefer more restrictive practices, I am certain that linters and other tooling will warn about a misplaced global, or if not, that could be filled as  a feature requested in those tools.
But thinking about restricting it in core Python? What for? And what else should be restricted? Should all no-op expressions be simply transformed into syntax errors? (like, just mentioning a variable in a line by itself?). At what point that language would not be Python anymore?
And finally, but not least important: an out-of-scope global is a clear reminder for any human reading the code that the following variable is intended to be used as a global - so it does has semantical meaning, if not syntactic  - and maybe the correct approach would be to do the reverse: to include declaring a top-level  global as a good practice in type-hinted code, since the goal there is to have the maximum information (both human and machine readable) about an entity at the point it is first mentioned in the code.

Pylint has a rule for this (W0604) and ruff inherited that rule, so yep, tooling will help avoid this if necessary.

I consider any name not bound by class or def statement, or not following PEP 8 constant guidelines likely to be modified by a function somewhere. global x at the global scope would only seem necessary to indicate a global name that's only vivified by a function call.

Regarding your last paragraph -- I'm not aware of any python style guides that recommends these top-level global declarations. So while it could be used that way, like type annotations, I don't think it's intended to be used this way.
